# How to Overlap Two Widgets in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, overlap

Expected output:

[image: This is a combination of a circle avatar with the color and and image on top of it]

This is a combination of a circle avatar with the color and and image on top of it.

Current output:

[image]

Code:

```
 leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: contentWithIcon[value]['color']),
```

How do i overlap both on top of each other?

image path:

```
assets/img/forex.png
```

Comment: Link to stack widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to overlap them or use the stack widget, CircleAvatar will handle this for you.

```
CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: contentWithIcon[value]['color'], 
             child: Image.asset("assets/img/forex.png "),)
```

be sure assets folder is added in pubspec.yaml

```
  assets:
    - assets/
```